# autohotkey / AHK seleniumbasic how to "for loop" or get all element.text

Tags: selenium-webdriver, autohotkey

Can someone help me to get all text values from element ?
now I only get the first element text. Can someone help to improve this code?
Here is my script:

```
driver := ComObjCreate("Selenium.FirefoxDriver") ; or ChromeDriver
driver.Get("https://www.google.com.hk/")

sleep, 2000
driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("selenium")
sleep, 2000
send,{enter}
sleep, 2000


h3Element := driver.FindElementByClass("LC20lb")                
abc := h3Element.text
msgbox,%abc%
```